# Amazon EC2 instance is getting spammed with different PHP filenames

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4

Our server has been attacked recently and looks something like the following in the logs:

```
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:43 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/ynm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:43 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/71.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/wadre.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/vm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/test.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/1q.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:45 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/1111.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:45 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/errors.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:46 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/q.php' not found or unable to stat
```

These attacks go on for hours sometimes and freezes the server.

How to protect against this? fail2ban?

Have banned the IP's manually but they change every time.

Thanks!

Comment: `fail2ban` is appropriate here, but you should probably figure out why a couple of 404s per second (which should consume *very* minimal resources) crash your server too.

Comment: You could whitelist CloudFront IP ranges in security groups, which enforces requests going through CloudFront. Integrate AWS WAF with CloudFront, which includes AWS Shield, and that may help to reduce this. Custom WAF rules should enhance protection. Use [this AWS script](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudfront-samples/tree/master/update_security_groups_lambda) to keep the CloudFront IPs up to date.

Answer (score 4):

These are common occurrences. Robots try to find insecure scripts and exploit them. You can't really avoid it, once you've got a web server on the Internet you'll see scans like this.

However since you're running on AWS EC2 you've got a number of options:

1. Use **[AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) (Web Application Firewall)** to protect your site against malicious attacks.
2. Use **[AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/)** - managed DDoS protection. Free.
3. Etc...

In any case being scanned like this shouldn't freeze your server. That freezing is likely being caused by something else - maybe a DDoS (hint: use *AWS Shield*) or some successful exploit of one of your PHP scripts that consumes the instance memory.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll definitely check out AWS WAF and AWS Shield!

Answer (score -2):

You can use this app, it's very useful to me. It's Fail2ban integration for AWS
ACL.

https://www.cloudar.be/integrating-fail2ban-with-aws-network-acls/

Comment: This may not work for long. AWS ACLs have a default limit of 20, and a maximum limit of 40 rules. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html Most of the server logs I've seen of public instances would hit that limit in minutes.

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Exchange, as they can expire, disappear, or change without notice. The best way to answer with a link is to quote (using `> ` on each line) the relevant parts, and provide the link as a citation. See [answer] for more info